# Why does the label not fully display?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I am learning how to use PyQt5 and I came across this issue where "my first label" does not complete display on my screen.

Display after running the code:

[image]

Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui  import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True) #enable highdpi scaling
QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True) #use highdpi icons

def window():
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  win = QMainWindow()
  win = QMainWindow()
  win.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)
  win.setWindowTitle("Tech with Aeijan")
  label = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
  label.setText("my first label!")
  label.move(50,50)

  win.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Comment: Try adding `label.adjust()` before `label.move(50,50)` line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QLabel adapts its contents based on the (possible) parent layout manager, but you didn't use any, so it doesn't know how to correctly display itself or adapt its size to do that.

The simplest solution is to call `label.adjustSize()`, which will cause the label to resize itself so that it will be able to display its contents.

That wouldn't be a very good idea, though: you are trying to use a fixed position for a widget (which is normally considered a bad thing to do, for plenty of reasons); the result will be that if the label text is too big and the user resizes the window, the text won't be completely visible as it should be, nor the label would know how to resize or eventually wrap its contents to do ensure that all its text is shown.

The *better* approach is to use a [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), but that is a solution reserved for simpler widgets (like a QWidget or a QDialog); a QMainWindow [doesn't work like that](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework), and it requires a [central widget to be set](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) to ensure that its contents are correctly displayed and managed.

In your case, you could simply use `self.setCentralWidget(label)`, but that would prevent you to add any other widget to your window.

A "container" widget should be used instead, and that widget would be set as the central one for the main window; then you can set a layout for that widget and add the label to it:

```
def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()

    central = QWidget()
    win.setCentralWidget(central)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    central.setLayout(layout)
    # alternatively, the above is the same as this:
    # layout = QVBoxLayout(central)

    label = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    label.setText("my first label!")
    layout.addWidget(label)

    # ...
```

Comment: I got an error saying that "QWidget" is not defined. I thought this was a typo so I tried "QWidgets" and I got the same error.

Comment: [`QWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) is part of `PyQt5.QtWidgets`, and is the base class for **all** widgets Qt uses. Be more careful to not mix import "styles". You should either use `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, ...` or import single classes like you did with `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow`, but with the latter you have to manually add each class to the import statements everytime you need one you've not already specified.

Comment: It works! The entire label shows now! Thank you so much.